# Nested Array Normalize with counter on depth

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve this problem that I came across, struggling to get to solution:

**Problem:**

> const arr = [4, [3,1],1,[[2], 1]];
>
> We need to sum all the elements * depth of the element.
>
> For example, for [4, [3,1],1,[[2], 1]] = 4*1 + 3*2 + 1*2 + 1*1 + 2*3 +
>   1*2 = 21

This is my solution, however, I am not getting correct value. Can someone solve this using ES5 and ES6?

```js
const b = [4, [3,1],1,[[2], 1]]; // 4*1 + 3*2 + 1*2 + 2*3 + 1*2 + 1*1

function addNormalize(arr, sum=0, depth=1) {
    for(let i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        const cur = arr[i];
        if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
            depth+=1;
            addNormalize(cur, sum);
        } else {
            sum+=cur * depth;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(addNormalize(b))
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat
Scroll to bottom part to see the implementation

Comment: Hey @tom10271 I'm not looking for implementation for flattening the array, I am looking for adding array (reduce) * depth of the element declared or am I missing something? Can you shred some light ?

Comment: I will flatten the array and then reduce it

Comment: But we don't want to add the array directly. We want to add the element * depth of the element. if we flatten, we loose the depth.  @tom10271

Comment: I have answered your original question with explainations

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty cleanly with `reduce()`

```js
const b = [4, [3,1],1,[[2], 1]];

function addNormalize(arr, depth = 1){
    if (arr.length == 0) return 0
    return arr.reduce((a,item) => a + (Array.isArray(item) ? addNormalize(item, depth+1) : depth * item), 0)
}
console.log(addNormalize(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code is not working is extremely simple. Primitive value like string, boolean, int, float etc. are not `passed by reference` but value. This means value is copied as an immutable value(you can change the original value in another function scope)

You should either receive the value returned by the recursive function called in:

```
    if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
        depth+=1;
        sum += addNormalize(cur, sum);
    }
```

or change sum to an object so that sum is passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

I made some corrections to your code, you were trying to calculate the result by passing a "reference" and that can't be done in javascript with primitives, also you were not passing the depth to the recursive call.

```js
const b = [4, [3,1],1,[[2], 1]]; // 4*1 + 3*2 + 1*2 + 1*1 + 2*3 + 1*2

function addNormalize(arr, depth=1) {
    let sum=0;
    for(let i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        const cur = arr[i];
        if (Array.isArray(cur)) { 
            sum += addNormalize(cur, depth+1);
        } else {
            sum+=cur * depth;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(addNormalize(b))
```